# remove item from javascript array on uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got this function to extend an array (groups) by checking a checkbox:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
     if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $(this).parent().data("groups").push("my");
          console.log($(this).parent().data("groups"));
      }
      else{
      //   $(this).parent().data("groups").pop();
      console.log($(this).parent().data("groups"));
       }

});

    <div class="item white" data-kpi="GDI" data-groups='["all", "numbers", "green", "square"]'>
<input type="checkbox" class="ps" name="add" value="my" />
</div>
```

I want to be able to remove the item again by unchecking the checkbox (there might be more than one 'my' group-items).

Comment: You can do this if you add something to the array that uniquely identifies the checkbox. Or if you don't care *which* item is removed, just use `$(this).parent().data("groups").pop()` as you already have in your code. Or what's the problem with that?

Comment: If you did `.data(this.id)` or anything else that is unique, you could actually remove it, for how do you remove a certain `my` from an array of `my`'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splice to remove an element from an array.

```
array = ['my', 'name', 'my'];
index = array.indexOf('my');
array.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: and the part for actually removing it?

Comment: I didn't understand the question. This actually removes the element